# Using a java constant in a Kotlin annotation parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, caching, spring-boot, kotlin

In Spring Boot (with Java) I usually put the cache names in static final strings, like this:

```
public static final String MY_CACHE_NAME = "cache_name"

@Cacheable(value = MY_CACHE_NAME)
```

But, when I have a java class with this cache names and I try to use in a Kotlin cached method, the Eclipse tells me this is not a "compile-time constant". Is there a way to solve this?

Outside eclipse, everything goes fine...

Comment: You can try to define your variable in Kotlin as a „const“

Answer (score 1):

That's quite odd, this should definitely work. You probably have a configuration problem. Check if your Kotlin plugin and your project use the same version of Kotlin, different versions often lead to odd compiler errors. Use the latest version in both places if possible.

This is the example code that I tried that worked perfectly well on `1.1.50` (it's nonsense, but it compiles):

- MyConstants.java

  ```
  public class MyConstants {
      public static final String MY_CACHE_NAME = "cache_name";
  }
  ```
- DemoApplication.kt

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  class DemoApplication

  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication::class.java, *args)
  }

  @Cacheable(MyConstants.MY_CACHE_NAME)
  fun someFunction() {}
  ```

Comment: I just realized it was an Eclipse problem. If I compile outside Eclipse, everything goes fine. 

Just to make sure, did your test was in Intelij?

I marking your answer... it's kind of a configuration problem. Tks!

Comment: Actually, I changed the question to the correct problem... so I will unmark your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Has the Eclipse plugin been updated to support whatever version of Kotlin you're using?

Comment: Yea, running into the same issue. Seems to be an eclipse thing.